# Extract coefficients and corresponding monomials from a given polynomial in SymPy

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy, polynomials

Given a symbolic **multivariate** polynomial `P`, I need to extract both its coefficients and corresponding monomials as lists:

```
def poly_decomp(P):
    ....
    return coeffs, monoms
```

such that `P` is the dot product of coefficients and monomials, e.g., if `P(x,y) = ax**2 + bxy + cy**2` then we should get `coeffs = [a, b, c]` and `monoms = [x**2, x*y, y**2]`.

Getting the coefficients is easy since the function is built in `coeffs = P.coeffs()`. However, I'm having trouble getting the monomials. Here the build in function returns a list of exponents, e.g., in the example above we would get `P.monoms() = [(2,0),(1,1),(0,2)]`.

Obviously the idea would be, provided a list of the variables `var=[x,y]`, to do something like

```
powers = P.monoms() 
monoms = [sympy.prod(x**k for x,k in zip(var, mon)) for mon in powers ]
```

However the polynomial class doesn't seem to offer a function that returns a list of variables. All I could find were the methods `free_symbols` and `free_symbols_in_domain` which return the sets `{a, b, c, x, y}` and `{a, b, c}`. So by taking their difference one could get the **set** `{x, y}`.

However then we are faced with the issue that the sets are unordered, hence converting it into a list might mess up the order in different ways depending on the number of variables.

I am kind of at a loss here. Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property `gens` (short for *generators*) holds a `tuple` of [symbols or other suitable objects](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/polys/basics.html#polynomials) that the polynomial is defined over.

```py
from sympy import symbols, Poly

x, y = symbols('x y')
p = Poly(x**3 + 2*x**2 + 3*x*y + 4*y**2 + 5*y**3, x, y)
q = Poly(x**3 + 2*x**2 + 3*x*y + 4*y**2 + 5*y**3, y, x)
print(p.gens)  # (x, y)
print(q.gens)  # (y, x)
```

So,

```
[prod(x**k for x, k in zip(p.gens, mon)) for mon in p.monoms()]
```

returns `[x**3, x**2, x*y, y**3, y**2]`.

Note also that the generators can be types other than symbols, for example:

```py
import sympy

x = sympy.symbols('x')
poly = sympy.poly(sympy.sqrt(2) * x**2)
print('generators: {g}'.format(g=poly.gens))
print('monomials: {m}'.format(m=poly.monoms()))
print('coefficients: {c}'.format(c=poly.coeffs()))
```

which prints:

```
generators: (x, sqrt(2))
monomials: [(2, 1)]
coefficients: [1]
```

where:

- `type(poly.gens[0])` is `<class 'sympy.core.symbol.Symbol'>`, and
- `type(poly.gens[1])` is `<class 'sympy.core.power.Pow'>`.

A relevant method is `sympy.polys.polytools.Poly.as_dict`, which returns a `dict` with keys that are monomials, and values that are the corresponding coefficients.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe late to answer, but just to supplement the great answer above:

In Sympy 1.8, a Poly object x has the attribute .args, i.e.:

```
import sympy as sp  

x = sp.Poly(x**3 + 2*x**2 + 3*x*y + 4*y**2 + 5*y**3)
x.args[1:] #returns (x,y)
```

and `x.args[1:]` will be sorted based on how you defined your symbols. For instance, if your polynomial has n variables in terms of the symbols:

```
a = sp.symbols('a:n')
```

then `x.args[1:]` would be in the order `(a0, ..., an)`. Knowing this and `x.monoms()`, I'm sure it could be put in the format that you wanted.